# Making Jsonobject using gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a Json which looks like this :

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Success",
    "data": {

    }
}
```

What i want to do is this:

```
public class Success {

@SerializedName("statusCode")
@Expose
private Integer statusCode;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private JSONObject data;

public Integer getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public JSONObject getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(JSONObject data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

The data here is a custom object which can always have different set of objects and arrays within which is why i just need it in JSONOBject.
But the data JSONObject is always empty. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think i don't understand really well you are saying that the data is always empty but in your Json there is nothing in your "data" object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `com.google.json.JsonObject` instead of `org.json.JSONObject`.

Gson doesn't know what a `JSONObject` is, because the class belongs to a different json library (json.org).

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited Code

```
  @Expose
    private Integer statusCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
        private ArrayList<Data> datas;

    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getData() {
        return datas;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Data> data) {
        this.datas = data;
    }
    }
```

#### Create Separate POJO class for Data

```
 public class Data{

        // parse json Object data
        //if data exists
        //as usual
        //like  @@SerializedName("message")
        //   @Expose
        //  private String message;

        }
```